# How to return a pointer in a function?

Tags: c, function, pointers

I have just started learning about pointers and how they can be passed to functions as arguments, and how they can have the same effects as arrays in functions.

And now I am curious how to instead, **return pointers in a function, or if this is possible?** That is my question.  I would like to know how to return a general pointer.

Comment: What is the problem? Is there anything you want to know that can't be answered by a basic c tutorial?

Comment: "return ... in a function" doesn't make sense, at least not to me. Do you want to return a pointer *from* a function, or to assign the return value of a called function to an lvalue of type "pointer-to-something"? Or a third option?

Comment: I guess I want to assign the return value of a called function to a pointer-to-something

Comment: @C_Intermediate_Learner This site isn't for basic C tutorials and that's what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it is possible to return pointer from functions.

```
int * FunctionReturningAnInteger()
{
   // this function returns integer pointer;
    int *integerPointer = malloc(sizeof *integerPointer); /* memory allocation */
   *integerPointer = 12;  
    return integerPointer; 
} 

char * FunctionReturningACharacter()
{
   // this function returns integer pointer;
    char*charPointer = malloc(sizeof *charPointer ); /* memory allocation */
   *charPointer = 'a';  
    return charPointer ; 
}
```

hope it's clear now to you

Comment: Thank you, I'd just like to know how to return a general pointer.

Comment: @C_Intermediate_Learner general Pointer in the sense ?

Comment: Anyway, just so you know: I upvoted this because this is the only answer that uses `malloc()` correctly.

Comment: `sizeof *charrPointer` should be `sizeof *charPointer`

Answer (score 0):

prototype for returning pointer

```
int* func();
float* func();
char* func();
```

Just define them whatever you want.

Comment: what general pointer you are talking about ? can you please share where exactly you stuck?

Comment: Sorry Vinay, it is the pointer that returns void I was trying to refer to

Answer (score 0):

As I can deduce from the question, you are trying to get a tutorial from here which is obviously not possible. You have to try yourself the examples and most importantly, you have to understand the concept of returning a pointer from a function.

> You can start with these questions::
>
> 1. When is returning pointer from a function good?
> 2. What do these pointers actually return ?
> 3. How to collect the returned pointer from a function ?

For instance you can compile and debug this example,

```
/* function to generate and retrun random numbers. */
int * getRandom( )
{
   static int  r[10];
   int i;
 
   /* set the seed */
   srand( (unsigned)time( NULL ) );
   for ( i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
   {
      r[i] = rand();
      printf("%d\n", r[i] );
   }
 
   return r;
}
 
/* main function to call above defined function */
int main ()
{
   /* a pointer to an int */
   int *p;
   int i;

   p = getRandom();
   for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
   {
       printf("*(p + [%d]) : %d\n", i, *(p + i) );
   }
 
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
int i;

/* returns a pointer to an int */
int *function1()
{
    return &i;
}

char c;

/* returns a pointer to a char */
char *function2()
{
    return &c;
}
```

Comment: Must there be an underscore, or is what Vinay did okay?  Also how do I apply this for a general pointer

Comment: No. Edited to change the function names. Any function name is OK. What do you mean by a general pointer?

Comment: @C_intermediate_learner_who_certainly_lacks_intermediate_and_even_basic_knowledge: what is this "general" pointer you keep talking about? `void *`? Or what?

Comment: @H2CO3; I hope this "General Pointer" will be introduced in the next C documetation :)

Comment: @haccks Surely it must be in C14 :P

Comment: @H2CO3  The 'general' pointer I was typing about is `void *`.  Thank you, for both your answer and your nice compliment.